# How do you create your own less variables and import them into other stylesheets with the rails asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, less

I'm using less css along with twitter-bootstrap-rails in an app and I can't figure out how to create my own custom less variables. I created a file called stylesheets/globals/variables.css.less that I'd like to use to define a custom color palette in.

I tried importing that file into other stylesheets where I want to use custom color variables but I keep getting an undefined variable error.

There's no issue with bringing variables over from the twitter-bootstrap rails gem. For instance @import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap"; in the booststrap_and_overrides.css.less file works just fine.

The only way to fix this is to run rake assets:precompile, but that's not a workable solution. Is there a way to use the variables at runtime?

Comment: Hey man, do let me know if you find the answer, we are going to something fairly similar down here :)

Comment: Haven't figured this out yet. Just resorted to hard coding in my custom colors instead of using less variables for the time being.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I ran into a similar problem. I fixed the problem by renaming my custom variable file to:

```
my_custom_variables.less
```

and adding:

```
@import "my_custom_variables";
```

to the top of the CSS file referencing my custom variables.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a better way to do this now? It seems very un-DRY to have to import your variables with each stylesheet you want to use in your app, especially if you use the rails convention of separate stylesheets for each model.